# Using Xcode5 to code in Java

Tags: java, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I have been developing Java code for doing data analysis in astronomy and physical sciences for several years using xemacs and JDE, which I have grown accustomed to and like. However, I would like to use all the wonderful features included in Xcode to make my coding easier and better.

I know that Apple encourages developing in objective C, but I don't have the time or motivation to start with this at this time. I know Java pretty well, and therefore, I want to stick with it, as least for now.

After several hours of searching the web, I haven't been able to find any decent instructions on how to setup and use Xcode under Mountain Lion or Mavericks to develop Java code. And I don't really care about all the features that are related to developing application for OS X or iOS, I am coding libraries of classes to do statistical data analysis. I just want a nice IDE to do it in, and I don't really like the look and feel of Eclipse, which is the standard for Java.

So, in the end, my question is very simple, but I cannot find the answer by googling: how does one develop in Java using Xcode5?

Comment: Have you given Intellij IDEA a try? http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: You basically have 3 choices: NetBeans, Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode did previously support java development but that was removed when Apple decided to stop supporting Java on OS X.

Either you need an old version of XCode, or you should go - which I would recommend you to do - with a Java IDE like Netbeans! eclipse and/or IntelliJ.  After installing oracle java 7, all of them run well.

Comment: I recommend Netbeans!

Comment: Note that this is given a modern machine that can run OS X 10.9.  For older machines stuck on OS 10.7 or 10.5 you have other options.